# What kind of TensorFlow should I use to predict if someone will like a certain place?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to TensorFlow and machine learning. I want to train TensorFlow to predict if someone will like certain places using the activities that they like. What kind of TensorFlow should I use?

This is my sample data.

```
ID  Hiking  Swimming    Eating  Surfing  Mountain Climbing  Beach

1    -27       31         12      11         -66             1

2    -44       65        -29      87         -49             3

3     6       -82         78     -79          16            -5

4     52      -36        -84     -37          75            -3

5     -7       36         86      50         -83             5
```

NOTE: Positive values mean they like it. Negative values mean they don't like it.

I expect to return a value like:
`Beach = 3`
if I input values for the first 5 columns like:

```
Hiking = -12
Swimming = 20
Eating = 10
Surfing = 50
Mountain Climbing = -40
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, asking for recommendations is considered off-topic on Stackoverflow, as it attracts opinionated answers, see [ask]. Additionally, your problem statement does not include anything on your value ranges, which is rather important for machine learning: Are you dealing with discrete ranges, or can values be in between? Does it imply an ordering, or are those arbitrary values?
There are also great resources that help you determine the right ML approach (Tensorflow has nothing to do with the choice of algorithm, it's just the implementation).

Comment: Hi @dennlinger. Thanks for the comment. As a newbie to machine learning, I do not know where to start. Can you tell me where to start to achieve my goal? The values are based on users of an app. The values describe how much they like or dislike a certain activity. For the place such as Beach on the example, It can range from -5 up to 5 based on the rating the user gave.

Comment: You can easily find resources on the right choice of algorithms by googling for that, although I would highly recommend to start by slowly working your way through tutorials, as well as some literature covering the details of it. Simply throwing ML at your problem will likely result in frustration and suboptimal results.

Comment: @dennlinger I know this is out of topic but I want to deploy tensorflow model via docker and had run this command "docker build --pull -t user/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel ." It's stuck after "Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...". Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

If you are new to deep learning, you can try stacking a DNN of your own. It will help the understanding of how Tensorflow works.

Example code:
[tf.estimator.DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier)